# ClassNotFoundException - PrestaShop 1.7.4.3

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Hello I have a problem with PrestaShop 1.7.4.3. After trying to log in to the Admin panel, errors appear as in the attached picture.

[[image: image here]

Answer (score 0):

I will be you, either I would reinstall my Prestashop, or I would install it somewhere else and I would put all the Vendor folder that is at the root to correct the problem.

Regards,